# What is the best practice to initialise StandardFileSystemManager

Tags: java, xcode, spring-boot, refactoring

Currently, I have my code as per below

```
@Service
public class MyFileService {
    private StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();

    public List<FileObject> listRemoteFiles() {
        try {
            manager.init();

            manager.resolveFile(someURL);


        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
        return Arrays.stream(remoteFiles)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

But I found that sometimes manager.init() throw an exception due to multiple registration

> FileSystemException :Multiple providers registered for URL scheme
>   "file".

Is there a best practise to create this StandardFileSystemManager? so it's only register 1 providers?

I’m guessing everytime I called listRemoteFiles() it will initialise manager. But my intention to init once and close at the very end.
Will this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the singleton design pattern to make sure only one object of `StandardFileSystemManager` gets created.

I see you are using `@Service` annotation. I am assuming its from spring. Why don't you register `StandardFileSystemManager` as spring bean and then autowire it in `MyFileService`? By default spring beans are singleton. So your code would look like

```
@Service
public class MyFileService {

    private final StandardFileSystemManager manager;

    @Autowired
    public MyFileService(StandardFileSystemManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public List<FileObject> listRemoteFiles() {
        try {
            manager.resolveFile(someURL);
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }

        return Arrays.stream(remoteFiles)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

and you can register `StandardFileSystemManager` as bean in any class that is marked with `@Configuration` as below

```
@Bean
public StandardFileSystemManager manager() {
    StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();
    manager.init(); 
    return manager;
}
```